# Symfony form custom constraint evaluation fails due to unexpected entity change time in repository

Tags: forms, symfony, constraints, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

In a Symfony 3.3.17 Application I have an Entity with a parameter using a custom Validation Constraint

```
class JobAd
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2048)
     * @JobAdAssert\JobAdUrlExists
     */
    protected $url = '';

    ...
}
```

The Constraint JobAdUrlExists looks like this

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class JobAdUrlExists extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Cant use URL "{{ string }}". Its in use already.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'job_add_url_exists.validator';
    }
}
```

and this is the JobAdUrlExistsValidator

```
class JobAdUrlExistsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    // ...

    public function validate( $value, Constraint $constraint )
    {
        // ...

        if( /* logic here */ ) {
            $this->context->buildViolation( $constraint->message )
                ->setParameter( '{{ string }}', $value )
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

The Form Type is defined as

```
class JobAdType extends AbstractType implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        // ...

        $builder->add( 'url', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => $translator->trans( 'URL' ),
            'required' => false,
            'translation_domain' => 'messages',
            'mapped' => true,
            'data' => $url
        ));

        // add other form fields ...
    }

    public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\JobAd',
            )
        );
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'job_ad';
    }
}
```

My Application logic creates a view like this

```
// ...

$jobAd = $jobAdRepository->findOneBy( array( 'url' => $job_ad_url ) );
$jobAdForm = $this->createForm( JobAdType::class, $jobAd );

if('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
    if( $request->request->has( 'job_ad' ) ) {
        $jobAdForm->handleRequest($request);
        if( $jobAdForm->isSubmitted() && $jobAdForm->isValid() ) {
            // ...
            $em->persist( $jobAd );
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}

return $this->render( $jobAdTemplate, array(
    'form_job_ad' => $jobAdForm->createView(),
));
```

And finaly - the twig view outputs the form like this

```
{{ form_start(form_job_ad) }}
{{ form_errors(form_job_ad) }}
{{ form_widget(form_job_ad.url) }}
{{ form_end(form_job_ad) }}
```

Now - when I insert a URL into the form field that triggers a validation error three things happen that confuse me a lot:

1. The validate method in the JobAdUrlExistsValidator builds the violation. But while evaluating if the URL exists I fetch the existing JobAds and surprisingly the the JobAd representing the one that is rendered in contect with the form right now has it's URL parameter set to the NEW (and potentialy wrong) URL already. Does that mean that the base Entity used to fill the form is changed BEFORE the validation actualy happens?
2. Although the call to $jobAdForm->isValid() is not returning true and therefore neither $em->persist() nor $em->flush() are called the form in the frontend does not output any errors and displays the new URL as its preset value. However the DB entry representing the Entity does NOT change - and therefore when loading the page again the URL is the old one again.
3. When entering a URL that should no fail when beeing checked by the constraint the validations says it's an error too. This is not surprising when remembering the observation in 1.) -> the URL parameter of the entity is changed before actualy checking anything and therefore when checking if the new url exists allready its obviously fails because it does exist - in the entry it should be inserted right now.

I am confused and a bit desperate now having no idea where to look for the problems solution...
Any hints are very welcome :-)

Comment: In your class JobAdUrlExists you need to escape `'` in your `$message` (maybe not related to your main question, but it can be problematic)

Comment: @v-gael y - thanks. True :-) But that doesn't help with the actual problem (like you said).